# Does Perl6 have a method for checking substring matches?

Tags: string, substring, raku

How can one check for substring matches in Perl?

The `index` method returns an `Int`:

```
"abc".index("b")
1
```

Using `defined`, the result can be turned into a `Bool`:

```
"abc".index("b").defined
True
```

Is this the idiomatic way or is there another method that returns a `Bool`?

Comment: What does the index method return in case the substring is not present ?

Comment: I guess it’s nil so you can test in an if condition for some value or nil that’s another way

Comment: `"abc".index("x").defined` result = `False`

Comment: my $org =“come”; my $new = S/c/m given $org; say $org;say $new; output: “come” “mome”. The operator S/// in case you want to find the substring and change it with other string

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The method is [`.contains`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/contains).

```perl6
say 'abc'.contains('b');  # True
```

There is also [`.starts-with`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/starts-with) and [`.ends-with`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/ends-with).

```perl6
say 'abc'.starts-with('c'); # False
say 'abc'.starts-with('a'); # True

say 'abc.txt'.ends-with('.txt') # True
```

You can look at the [Str](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str) docs for more methods.